# Auto-fill attribution of similar feature classes via connectivity rules (Geometric Network)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, geometric-network, connection, arcgis-water-utilities

I am working with water utility data.  I am trying to figure a way to make feature types connected to the Mains (primary distribution water pipes) automatically fill certain attributes when they are created that already been filled in the Main record.

For example I want to have new service connections (pipes to houses & businesses) that are connected to the Geometric Network (GN) via a Main, to grab certian attribution from the main that the two features have in common.    For instance service area.  And, I want to have this happen when the editor creates the new and connects to the GN.

I am thinking that there should be a way to use the connectivity rules to do this.

Perhaps some sort of python modification to the [Transfer Attributes Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/transfer-attributes.htm) where the search distance is replaced with connectivity.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Can you please confirm that you are using ArcGIS version **10.0**?

Comment: Esri have the Attribute Assistant tool available (see my post here http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/178324/64785) but the current release requires minimum ArcGIS 10.2.1.  There may still be a release available for 10.0, but it will require some digging as the links I've just tried were all dead.

Comment: The attribute assistant would solve the problem the way I described it.  I was thinking more of something actively running in the background, or on some interval. For instance if a polygon where the attribution is coming from changed (which happens frequently) then the attributes could pick that change up based on connectivity as opposed to spatial location.  Thanks for the idea though!